# Intellij IDEA, scala, show all errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I cannot get any useful error reporting in IDEA 14. Errors are nicely underlined but it would be nice if  I could somewhere see a collection of all the errors I have in my code.

Problems monitor is not showing anything, scala facet wont load, I', lost.

I would be satisfied with a window that would just collect all the errors I have underlined in my code, or a functionality similar to F2 shortcut (go to next problem) if it would work across whole solution, not only within a file.

Comment: Probably not the kind of answer for which you're searching, but I gave up on Intellij IDEA for scala a while ago. The support is not very good; I think it is because they decided to implement their own parsing / typer inference engine rather than use the Scala presentation compiler, and this leads to many issues. Scala-IDE is quirky, but the latest 4.0.0-m2 release is pretty good and can handle properly just about anything you can throw at the compiler, including macros.

Comment: I have also tried Scala-IDE. IDEA has much better type recognition and some other features, but I would be happy with scala-IDE if I could get it to work properly. I have tried 4.RC2, somehow activator eclipse doesen't work anymore ans I am really not fluent enought in eclipse ecosystem to fix all the classpath and other build path errors.